# Client requesting an API call from the server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to implement a search bar that allows the client to search for results from the nutritionix API (https://rapidapi.com/msilverman/api/nutritionix-nutrition-database/).

I would like to display the results as the user is typing so i've currently implemented an event handler on the search bar where on every 'key up' the client makes a request to the server, to make a request to the API to search with the current value of the search box, and then return it to the client.

This does seem a bit long-winded to me but i couldn't think of any other way to make this work whilst avoiding making direct API calls client side.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
  <input class="food-search" type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Then on the client-side:

```
foodSearch.addEventListener('keyup', async function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let response = await fetch(`localhost:3000/api/${foodSearch.value}`);
  console.log(response);
  let data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
})
```

And on the server:

```
app.get('/api/:term', (req, res) => {
  const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: `https://nutritionix-api.p.rapidapi.com/v1_1/search/${req.params.term}`,
  params: {fields: 'item_name,item_id,brand_name,nf_calories,nf_total_fat'},
  headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'nutritionix-api.p.rapidapi.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'bb139f2718mshaa7b73c60324df5p1fc8f3jsn1de77b6d9fb7'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  res.send(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  res.send(error);
});
```

})

I'm currently getting a "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource" error on the client side. It's not reaching the server at all, i can access the route directly and i get a successful API call, but i'm not having any success client side.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the network error you get?

Comment: @VLAZ

<anonymous> http://localhost:3000/js/script.js:64
<anonymous> http://localhost:3000/js/script.js:67
AsyncFunctionThrow self-hosted:642

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.